# nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm working on a simple spring + mybatis project but encountered an unexpcted error and tried to find the answer from google but failed for almost one day. Now in headache. I need to get your support to have this issue fixed, or I couldn't sleep well. Thanks for your support.

The error messge is as follows,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mybatis.dao.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
```

[image]

[Download Project Source Code Here!!](http://ty.danggui.fun:9000/files/MyBatis-Spring-master.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=kdiiekd%2F20200403%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200403T145746Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c0708ae207099e26fa2f3194c1d3c2883f34a592523499dede78d24984d4b016)

The password to unzip is `helloworld`

> 1. Download source code
> 2. Click on TestController and right click and run it, then you will face the same issue.

Here is the create table script for this project.

```
CREATE DATABASE mybatis;
USE mybatis;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid` tinyint(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usex` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks!!!

Comment: Your support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, can you just show the minimum reproducible error in StackOverflow questions? No screenshots, no attachments with passwords etc... I think just the UserDao interface, the Controller and the applicationContext.xml would have sufficed.

Comment: Post your `userDao` class and `userController` class.

Comment: @Jacob I have corrected some mistakes that cause the exception and upload it to [GitHub](https://github.com/harawata/so-61014611). See the commit log for the details. As you seem to be new to this, I would suggest learning basics about the tools you use e.g. maven, mybatis, spring, spring-boot, etc.. :)

Comment: @ave really appreciated for your support. And I learnt much from your corrected one. Yep, I'm new to this and learning the basic of mybatis and spring etc.

Answer (score 0):

The MapperScannerConfigurer is the one that scans your @Mapper classes and should generate Spring Beans for them.

I noticed that the basePackage name is wrong:

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.dao"/><!-- <- com.mybatis.dao -->
  <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it's one of the errors in the project.